# Android Kotlin - How to read NFC tag inside Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, ndef

I found some recent posts here about reading NFC Tags with Android.
The conclusion that I got is that to performing an NFC read action triggers a separated intent.

What I want to achieve is that **only** my current activity is reading the NDEF message from a NFC tag in text/plain format.

So first question:
Is it neccessary to list the intent-filter in my manifest?

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

I think this is not neccessary since I do **not** want to launch my app via NFC tag event, right?

Second question: How do I keep my NFC reading logic/functions related to my app/activity?

After

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

I go to my current Activity and initialize the NFC Adapter onCreate:

```
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
```

What would be the next step to read the nfc tag NDEF message?
Found something related with intent in dispatch foreground:

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 

    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

Would be nice if someone has an idea/example (Kotlin) how just to read a NFC tag 
from the activity **without** stuff like launching/beaming NFC actions.

In iOS e.g. there is a simple NFC session when needed in a VC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, if you only want to receive tags while your `Activity` is in the foreground, you can register for this at runtime. What you're looking for is the `enableForegroundDispatch` method on `NfcAdapter`. You can register a `PendingIntent` for the specific types of tags you want to filter to, and your `Activity` will receive an `Intent` in `onNewIntent()` whenever a tag is detected.

A quick example in Kotlin of what this would look like if you're looking for only `IsoDep` compatible NFC tags:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)?.let { nfcAdapter ->
        // An Intent to start your current Activity. Flag to singleTop
        // to imply that it should only be delivered to the current 
        // instance rather than starting a new instance of the Activity.
        val launchIntent = Intent(this, this.javaClass)
        launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

        // Supply this launch intent as the PendingIntent, set to cancel
        // one if it's already in progress. It never should be.
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        )

        // Define your filters and desired technology types
        val filters = arrayOf(IntentFilter(ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED))
        val techTypes = arrayOf(arrayOf(IsoDep::class.java.name))

        // And enable your Activity to receive NFC events. Note that there
        // is no need to manually disable dispatch in onPause() as the system
        // very strictly performs this for you. You only need to disable 
        // dispatch if you don't want to receive tags while resumed.
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(
            this, pendingIntent, filters, techTypes
        )
    }
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
        val tag = intent.getParcelableExtra<Tag>(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
        IsoDep.get(tag)?.let { isoDepTag ->
            // Handle the tag here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Sir! Excactly what I was looking for. Very Thanks.